# MySQL said: "#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" in nested select Query Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL query like :

```
select barno, case_number 
from barno_cases 
where case_number IN
   (select case_number 
    from barno_cases 
    where filed BETWEEN "1963-01-01" AND "2014-12-09" 
    AND section="5"
) 
Group by barno, case_number Order by barno"
```

it give error : "#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"
i don't know what's going wrong.

Any idea.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two simultaneous queries because mysqli uses unbuffered queries by default (for prepared statements; it's the opposite for vanilla `mysql_query`). You can either fetch the first one into an array and loop through that, or tell mysqli to buffer the queries (`using $stmt->store_result()`).

See [here](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysqli_query&lang=en&scope=404quickref) for details.

Comment: @Yash Check if the query works yourself in something like PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thanks @Jordy Query run successfully for single Select query but not in nested query.

Comment: @Yash, thats why i am saying You can't run two simultaneous queries

Comment: @Yash, Use `''` instead of `""` in `filed` values.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the query worked, it's a very dumb to structure it. Consider:

```
select DISTINCT barno, case_number 
from barno_cases 
where filed BETWEEN '1963-01-01' AND '2014-12-09' 
AND section='5'
Order by barno
```

(BTW: the 'GROUP BY is also very innefficient, and you've quoted the value in the predicate incorrectly)

Comment: your answer is useful but i want to search in only section='5' rows but i want result according to case number and entered input section.

Comment: Sorry - I don't know what you are talking about. These conditions (case number, enetered input selection) are not described in your question. And happy to point you in the right direction not to write your code for you.

Comment: I understand and don't have any wrong way to go my concept from my side. Ok The section value depends on user input for output and section='5' is for searching. i don't want section='5' row for output.